# Flutter state and streams

Tags: flutter, stream, state

This kind of a code structure question. I have two pages in my app page1 and page2. Page2 y irrelevant except that you can navigate from page1 to page2 and back to page1.

In page1 I use this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/language_pickers) . It shows a dialog and you provide a call back with the selected language. I use a `Stream` because I have to load a predefined language from shared preferences which is async. My intention is to pass `_lang` to page2. The code as I have it is working as expected. But if you navigate back to page1 from page2 you get the default language because I didn't call setState. If I put a `setState` inside the callback the changes don't persist because the stream gets rebuild every time. And I cannot take the stream out if I want the default to show on start.

```
StreamBuilder(
                  stream: langStream.stream,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      _lenguaje = snapshot.data;
                      return ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(Icons.language),
                        title: Text('${snapshot.data.name}'),
                        trailing: Text('Your Lang'),
                        onTap: () {
                          showLangPicker(
                            context,
                            (Language lang) {
                              _lang = lang;
                              langStream.update(lang);
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Container();
                    }
                  },
                ),
```

I'm in chicken-egg situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use some sort of [state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple). I would use [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). How you would accomplish this is you would have an app level Model that extends `ChangeNotifier` called `languageModel` or `settingsModel`. The model would look something like this:

```dart
class SettingsModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  Language _lang;
  Language get lang => _lang;
  set lang(Language lang) {
    _lang= lang;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Then in page two when you get your language just call:

```dart
Provider.of<SettingsModel>(context, listen: false).lang = yourSelected Language
```

Then in your `ListView` you can retrieve the language by the following:
calling `Provider.of<SettingsModel>(context).lang` or by using a `Consumer` Widget as shown in the first link.

I hope this helped, and you may need to do more research on state management with provider to implement this, but using some form of state management is the cleanest solution to your problem, so you are not working around the framework instead of letting it help you.

Comment: With this approach I would have to reset the language to the default if the user cancels the flow or if it completes it. I will consider this anyway.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you set the model to be over your whole widget tree, it will last throughout the app. If you wanted it to save the language on closing and reopening the app you could use Shared Preference: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value

Comment: This method does not persist through page pushes. And im already using shared pref. As the post says.

Comment: @loki , Where are you declaring your `ChangeNotifierProvider` that provides `SettingsModel`? To make it global you must declare it above `MaterialApp`.